# PHP Shorthand Syntax to AND statements

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, shorthand

I am trying to implement the logical connective AND, and was wondering if this shorthand notation is allowed:

```
$hasPermissions &= user_hasAppPermission($user_id, $permission);
```

Or do i have to do this:

```
$hasPermissions = $hasPermissions && user_hasAppPermission($user_id, $permission);
```

Comment: It *could* work, but strictly *by accident*. If your variable was a true boolean before and the function returns a true boolean, then the implicit typecasting will lead to the right result. But really, you shouldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shorthand `&=` is a [bitwise assignment operation](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.bitwise.php), which is not equivalent to your second statement.  That would be the same as doing (note the single ampersand):

```
$hasPermissions = $hasPermissions & user_hasAppPermission($user_id, $permission);
```

From what I can see, your "long" statement seems fine as is.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, these [logical operations](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) are available:

**AND**

```
$val1 && $val2
$val1 and $val2
```

**OR**

```
$val1 || $val2
$val1 or $val2
```

**NOT**

```
! $val
```

**XOR**

```
$val1 xor $val2
```

Additionally, have a [look at this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). The two operators `&&` and `||` have a different precedence as `and` and `or`.

Thus, your **second option** is the way to go:

```
$hasPermissions = $hasPermissions && user_hasAppPermission($user_id, $permission);
```

BTW: I'd propose to **always use `===` to compare for equality**. === ensures that the types of its operands are identical and the values are, while `==` casts values.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
$hasPermissions = (($hasPermissions) && (true === user_hasAppPermission($user_id, $permission))) ? true : false;
```